# How do I play a video that I have uploaded in HTML5?

Tags: html

So, I want to be able to play a video that I have just uploaded via an input tag. The code will probably look nothing like this, but this is the basic idea:

```html
<input type = "file" id = "uploadedFile">
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="uploadedFile" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Help would be much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Just selecting the file in this input will not upload it.

Comment: I get that, but what should I do instead?

Comment: Add submit button, and handle when form submit. You can upload the video somewhere and return the location to play it in video tag.